# Facebook credits java jsp callback example

Tags: java, facebook, jsp, callback, credits

I could not find an example of using the facebook credits api to create a callback using Java & JSP. I am posting my Java/JSP version of the callback.php example. Remember to replace the appId and secretKey variables with your apps ID and Key:

callback.jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.net.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.security.*" %>
<%@ page import= "javax.crypto.*" %>
<%@ page import= "javax.crypto.spec.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser" %>
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONObject"%> 
<%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%> 

<%!
    //decode input string to base 64
    public byte[] base64UrlDecode(String input){
        return new Base64(true).decode(input.replace("-","+").replace("_","/").trim());
    }

    public String base64UrlEncode(byte[] input){        
        Base64 encoder = new Base64();
        String encodedInput = "";       
        try{
            encodedInput = encoder.encodeBase64URLSafeString(input);            
        }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encodedInput;
    }
    /*
    * http://javaboutique.internet.com/tutorials/InitForms/special.html
    */
    public String replace(String s, String one, String another) {
        // In a string replace one substring with another
        if (s.equals("")) return "";
        String res = "";
        int i = s.indexOf(one,0);
        int lastpos = 0;
        while (i != -1) {
                res += s.substring(lastpos,i) + another;
                lastpos = i + one.length();
                i = s.indexOf(one,lastpos);
        }
        res += s.substring(lastpos);  // the rest
        return res;  
    }

    public Map parseSignedRequest(String signedRequest, String secretKey){

        Map data = null;

        if(signedRequest != null){

            String[] split = signedRequest.split("\\.", 2);

            //Get signature and payload data portions of signed request string
            String encoded_sig = split[0];
            String payload = split[1];
            JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
            //parse json object

            try {
                data = (Map) parser.parse(new String(base64UrlDecode(payload)));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            String algorithm = (String) data.get("algorithm");
            String userID = ((String) data.get("user_id"));
            String authToken= ((String) data.get("oauth_token"));           
            //
            String signature = "";
            String expectedSignature = "";          
            if(!algorithm.equalsIgnoreCase("HMAC-SHA256")){
                System.out.println("ERROR: unknown algorithm");
                return null;
            }

            byte[] sig = base64UrlDecode(encoded_sig);      

            try{            
                //Decode
                Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
                SecretKeySpec key =  new SecretKeySpec(secretKey .getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
                mac.init(key);
                byte[] expectedSig = mac.doFinal(payload.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                signature = base64UrlEncode(sig);
                expectedSignature = base64UrlEncode(expectedSig);                       
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(!signature.equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                if(!signature.equalsIgnoreCase(expectedSignature)){
                    System.out.println("ERROR: Bad signed JSON signature");
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }//end if
        return data;
    }//
%>

<%
    //facebook code
    String appId = "xxxxxxx";
    String secretKey = "xxxxxxxxxx";    

    String errorReason = request.getParameter("error_reason");
    String signedRequest = request.getParameter("signed_request");
    String responseType = request.getParameter("response_type");

    /*
    * Parse the signed_request to verify it's from Facebook
    */
    Map requestMap = parseSignedRequest(signedRequest, secretKey);

    // Grab values passed to this callback
    String method = request.getParameter("method");
    String order_id = request.getParameter("order_id");
    JSONObject item = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject returnData = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray itemArray = new JSONArray();
    String returnvalue = "";

    if (requestMap == null) {
        // Handle an unauthenticated request here
        System.out.println("ERROR: Handle an unauthenticated request here");
    }

    if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("payments_status_update")){
        //grab the order status
        String nextState = "";
        String status =  request.getParameter("status");
        String orderId =  request.getParameter("order_id");     

        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        Map userjson = null;

        try {
            userjson = (Map) parser.parse(request.getParameter("order_details"));   
        }catch(Exception pe) {}

        // Write your apps logic here for validating and recording a
        // purchase here.
        // 
        // Generally you will want to move states from `placed` -> `settled`
        // here, then grant the purchasing user's in-game item to them.
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("placed")) {
            nextState = "settled";
            item.put("status",nextState);
            item.put("order_id",orderId);
            //display date or add code to insert into a database
            JSONArray itemsArray=(JSONArray)userjson.get("items");
            for(int i=0; i < itemsArray.size(); i++){
                JSONObject itemObj = (JSONObject)itemsArray.get(i);
                System.out.println("item[" + i + "]= Buyer(" + userjson.get("buyer") + ") purchased Qty(" + userjson.get("amount") + ") " + itemObj.get("title") + " @ $" + itemObj.get("price"));
            }               
        }
        // Compose returning data
        returnData.put("content", item);
        returnData.put("method", "payments_status_update");
        returnvalue = returnData.toJSONString();        
    } else if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("payments_get_items")) {                 

        String item_info = request.getParameter("order_info");
        //remove escape characters
        item_info = item_info.replaceAll("\"", "");

        if (item_info.equalsIgnoreCase("abc123")) {
            // Per the credits api documentation, you should pass in an item 
            // reference and then query your internal DB for the proper 
            // information. Then set the item information here to be 
            // returned to facebook then shown to the user for confirmation.
            item.put("title","BFF Locket");
            item.put("price",1);
            item.put("description","This is a BFF Locket...");
            item.put("image_url","http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png");
            item.put("product_url","http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/21.png");          
        } else {

            // For the sake of the sample, we will default to this item if 
            // the `order_info` reference passed from your JS call is not matched 
            // above.
            item.put("title","A Facebook Hat");
            item.put("price",1);
            item.put("description","The coolest hat you\'ve ever seen.");
            item.put("image_url","http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/740.png");
            item.put("product_url","http://www.facebook.com/images/gifts/740.png");
        }
        itemArray.add(item);
        returnData.put("content", itemArray);
        returnData.put("method", "payments_get_items");
        returnvalue = returnData.toJSONString();            
    }
    //return output data
    out.print(returnvalue);
    out.flush();
%>
```

Comment: Why are you using a JSP? A simple Servlet will do...

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this tutorial](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/). This will help you to use facebook api after creating appID and secreat.